# calculating the query response time of a search engine over the internet

Tags: java, search, browser

I am think of designing a software, such that it takes a keyword as an input as well as the choice of the search engines via `checkboxes` from the user.
Then it will calculate the search engine which can deliver fastest result among the selected search engine.
It  might show the statistics about the time and memory it had taken to search that keyword on different search engine.
I have designed the part of it in java but seeks for any support if I can get a way to figure out the best currently working search engine?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work.  On a number of levels.

1. I don't think it is practical to figure out the fastest search engine.  The effective speed will depend on where the user is, what his ISP is (and its peering arrangements), the time of day, day of week, etc.  The only way to figure it out is with extensive measurement *from the user's* browser.
2. The fastest search engine for a given user query will depend on the complexity of the query.  You can't model that.
3. People don't normally choose search engines based on their speed.  There are far more important criteria for choosing.  For example, many people think that the best search engine is the one that serves the best search results.
4. Given the above, you are **unlikely** to get an answer that actually help you.  (Assuming that you don't consider advice like mine to be helpful.  I disagree.  This is intended to be helpful by being realistic.)
5. But lets assume that there was a good answer, and that this was a worthwhile project.  Do you really think that asking StackOverflow is a good strategy?  What's to stop someone (say me) from doing the following:

   - Spot that this is a good business opportunity (hmmmm)
   - Work out a good way to do it (hmmmm)
   - Build my own app, or browser plugin or whatever.
   - Get it to market before you
   - Not tell you how I did it!

Comment: I knew that the StackOverflow is not to discuss such thing but still I have to ask because I can't figure out what to do